# Partial update tensor based on boolean mask in TensorFlow

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

I want to update part of the tensor based on some conditions.

I know that TensorFlow tensors are immutable so creating a new tensor would be ok for me.
I tried `tensor_scatter_nd_update` method but I couldn't make it work

This is code that I want to replicate in TensorFlow written in NumPy.

```py
import numpy as np

a = np.random.random((1, 3))
b = np.array([[0, 1, 0]])

c = np.zeros_like(a)
mask = b == 1
c[mask] = np.log(a[mask])
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In TensorFlow, we do not update tensors that are in fact immutable objects. Instead we create new tensors from other tensors like in functional languages.

````py
import tensorflow as tf

a = tf.random.uniform(shape=(1, 3))
b = tf.constant([[0, 1, 0]], dtype=tf.int32)

c = tf.zeros_like(a)
mask = b == 1
c_updated = tf.where(mask, tf.math.log(a), c)
# [[ 0.      , -4.175911,  0.      ]]```
````